# Extract text from html using in the same format as in html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**Code:**

```
body_text = BeautifulSoup(open(html)).text
```

In the html page, line like 1.        ETA basis expected metocean conditions gets splitted into lines while extracting, need to resolve this.

I used string formatting conditions like

```
body_html = str(BeautifulSoup(open(html_file)))
body_html = body_html.replace('\n', ' ') #to remove all new lines
body_html = body_html.replace('/>', '/>\n') # add new lines so that texts from two different tags do not extracted in same line
```

Sample HTML pages:https://easyupload.io/sh02xi

Is there any better way to extract texts in the same format as we visualize in html?

Comment: try
`soup =BeautifulSoup(open(html_file))`
`html = soup.prettify()`

Answer (score 0):

`html2text` works better for text extraction, when texts needs to be extracted in the same format as in html:

```
h = html2text.HTML2Text()
h.body_width = 0
h.ignore_links = True
h.ignore_images = True
print(h.handle(html_string))
```